# Exclude a specific series from exporting to csv

Tags: csv, highcharts, export-to-csv, react-highcharts

I'm using HighCharts library to plot some data in gauge chart. My chart looks like the image below.

[image]

To achieve this plot, I'm using solid gauge and gauge together using series option, (solid gauge for the semicircular and gauge for the dial.)

```
...
series: [
  {
    name: 'solidgauge',
    type: 'solidgauge',
    data: [data.value],
    ...
  },
  {
    name: 'gauge',
    type: 'gauge',
    data: [data.value],
    ...
  },
]
...
```

Obviously the data for both series is identical, so when I export the chart into csv file, the library create two columns with same data and I want to change this behavior and export only one of series, but after a lots of search, I couldn't find any option in highcharts to exclude a specific series.

[image]

How can I do that? (I'm not familiar with exporting customization, answer with little code sample would be great for start creating my own.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the `getCSV` method and hide the series before the proceed:

```js
var H = Highcharts;

H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'getCSV', function(proceed) {
  var result;

  this.series[1].hide();
  result = proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
  this.series[1].show();

  return result;
});
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/109a7vek/

Also, you can edit the generated data in the `exportData` event:

```js
H.addEvent(H.Chart, 'exportData', function(e){
  e.dataRows.forEach(function(el){
    el.splice(2, 1);
  });
});
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/du7nz2hy/

Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: This works, but I feel like Highcharts could support this in it's API

Comment: Hi @Jon Freedman, You can post your idea on Highcharts user voice: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api